# Wordpress dynamic_sidebar not parsing, deleting changes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi fellow Programmers,

I'm relatively new to Wordpress since I usually used Typo3, so I have a question regarding the custom sidebars in WP.

I have following code in my functions.php

```
function custom_sidebars()
{

  register_sidebars(4, array
  (
    'name' => __('Panel Startseite %d', 'me'),
    'id' => 'panel-home-%d',
    'description' => 'Widget Position for home panel',
    'class' => 'panel-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-panel-%d">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="panel-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
  ));

  $args2 = array
  (
    'name' => __('Short Bio Sidebar', 'me'),
    'id' => 'shortbio-id',
    'description' => 'Widget Position for short bio',
    'class' => 'shortbio-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-bio">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
  );
  register_sidebars(1, $args2);

}

add_action('widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars');
```

I want to add 4 panels for info on my home page and in the footer another small field for the author to add a bio or change it.

Here is my code from my index.php

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="inner">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('panel-home-1'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="inner">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('panel-home-2'); ?>
      </div>
 ... and so on
```

Same implementation is in footer.php at a given position.

My Problems are:

- Content I add via backend menu themes -> widgets doesn't show up and is deleted next time I open the backend .
- There are no errors in the wp-content/debug.log , I fixed all common ones after activating the option in wp-config.php

How can I fix this, what are my basic thinking mistakes?

Best Regards sKylo

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all good. Just one mistake, you are using `%d` to concatenate the decimals after your id. But that is not necessary since %d is automatically added to the supplied id. Please find codex link at the end of this answer.

So, I removed the %d from the id section of your code and now it works.

**Solution:**

```
function custom_sidebars()
{

  register_sidebars(4, array
  (
    'name' => __('Panel Startseite %d', 'me'),
    'id' => 'panel-home',
    'description' => 'Widget Position for home panel',
    'class' => 'panel-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-panel">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="panel-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
  ));

  $args2 = array
  (
    'name' => __('Short Bio Sidebar', 'me'),
    'id' => 'shortbio-id',
    'description' => 'Widget Position for short bio',
    'class' => 'shortbio-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-bio">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
  );
  register_sidebars(1, $args2);

}

add_action('widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars');
```

and

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="inner">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('panel-home'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="inner">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('panel-home-2'); ?>
      </div>
 ... and so on
```

You do not need to add %d to id of register_sidebars. Please read the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars),
it says:

"%d" is added automatically to supplied 'id' value after the first; e.g., "Sidebar-1", "Sidebar-2", "Sidebar-3", etc.

Comment: thx a lot mate ! It works now as intended. But wait, there is a big sum of inactive sidebars on widget admin interface. How do I remove them, hide them maybe?

Comment: you are welcome. click on the widget and it will show you delete option at the bottom of it.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem don't forget to check it as the right answer. Accepting the answer helps other people track that the issue is resolved for your question.